# jQuery Media Player Controls

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I got some javascript functions that control a media player object (like volumeUp(), play(), nextSong(), ect...).
I want to create some jQuery controls for the functions - controls like sliders to control the volume/time, play/pause buttons and so on.

How can I design or create such controls using JQuery?
I tried the built-in jQuery UI slider/buttons, but I don't really know how to design it (I know css).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can design it from http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ or download individual theming from here http://jqueryui.com/download